# Does Zig's HTTP client allow you to get access to the file descriptor for the socket?

Tags: http, sockets, client, filehandle, zig

It's not clear if Zig exposes the filehandle descriptor for the socket in  `client.request.reader()`? Does it? And if so how do you get access to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From truemedian,

> Short answer: no
>
> Long answer: yes, if you're willing to depend on implementation details `client.connection.?.data.stream.handle`.

Source: https://github.com/orhun/zig-http-benchmarks/issues/16